# Can I use next layer's output as current layer's input by Keras?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, keras, lstm

In text generate mission, we usually use model's last output as current input to generate next word. More generalized, I want to achieve a neural network  that regards next layer's finally hidden state as current layer's input. Just like the following(what confuses me is the decoder part):

[image: encoder-decoder]

But I have read Keras document and haven't found any functions to achieve it.

Can I achieve this structure by Keras? How?

Comment: How do you have your words encoded?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I have updated the encoder structure. But what confuses me is the decoder part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is an autoencoders, you can find similar structures in Keras.

But there are certain details that you should figure it out on your own. Including the padding strategy and preprocessing your input and output data. Your input cannot get dynamic input size, so you need to have a fixed length for input and outputs. I don't know what do you mean by arrows who join in one circle but I guess you can take a look at [Merge](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) layer in Keras (basically adding, concatenating, and etc.)

You probably need 4 [sequential](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) model and one final [model](https://keras.io/models/model/) that represent the combined structure.

One more thing, the decoder setup of LSTM (The Language Model) is not dynamic in design. In your model definition, you basically introduce a fixed inputs and outputs for it. Then you prepare the training correctly, so you don't need anything dynamic. Then during the test, you can predict each decoded word in a loop by running the model once predict the next output step and run it again for next time step and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The structure you have showed is a custom structure. So, Keras doesn't provide any class or wrapper to directly build such structure. But **YES**, you can build this kind of structure in Keras.

So, it looks like you need LSTM model in backward direction. I didn't understand the other part which probably looks like incorporating previous sentence embedding as input to the next time-step input of LSTM unit.

I rather encourage you to work with simple language-modeling with LSTM first. Then you can tweak the architecture later to build an architecture depicted in figure.

Example:

- [Text generation with LSTM in Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py)

Comment: Actually I had read and run the text generation example before asking this question. But it seems to directly generate words without output feedback. I also have read some codes about encoder-decoder model. But I have no idea how to tweak the architecture to achieve architecture depicted in the figure. Can you show me some way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "without output feedback"?

Comment: For example, the model depicted in the figure uses the output 'Mary' to generate next output 'was', then uses 'was' to generate 'hungry'. According to my understanding this's a kind of output feedback.

Comment: But what I really concern about is how to use the 'Decode-Word' layer's previous sentence embedding as input to the next time-step input of 'Decode Sentence' layer's LSTM unit.

Comment: @aweight usually deep neural networks use output feedback, you might have wrong understanding about deep neural architectures. I encourage you to see some article and read some papers to get more ideas. one thing that i can say, the model you are looking for is already developed and its not difficult to build.

Comment: I will try to figure it out. Thanks a lot!